# Map the Caps Lock key to the Super L key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, keyboard-layout, chromebook

I'm on chromebook using crouton to run xfce.

I already mapped the volume up key using the command 'amixer set Master 5%+' in the keyboard application shortcut menu.

Is there a command like that for the Caps Lock or any other easy method to achieve this?

Comment: Does the command `setxkbmap -option caps:super` result in the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) is an application that maps keys to other keys. It is a program that you start up in the background when you log in. I have not tried it personally, but you should be able to set it up to map Caps Lock to some other key.